# How to get the 4 first child in one nodeValue

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am looking for a way to automatically get the 4 cells of a table row with xpath and PHP.

The code looks like this :

```
$elements = $xPath->query(
    "//table/tbody[2]/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tr[1]/td/table/tr[2]/td[1]");
```

If I change the last digit I can navigate inside the table row. But would there be a way to get cell1, cell2, cell3 and cell4 in the same nodeValue.

(I tried stringjoin but it says invalid function)

Comment: Could you please present HTML/XML example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `position()`

in your case, if you want the first 4 entries

```
[position() >= 1 and not(position() > 4)]
```

put in your example it would look like this:

```
$elements = $xPath->query("//table/tbody[2]/tr/td/
    table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tr[1]/td/table/tr[2]/
    td[position() >= 1 and not(position() > 4)]");
```